# ng-repeat, доступ к значению массива по ключу

Tags: angularjs

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Хочу доступиться к значению массива по ключу ( в блоке blockquote), но ничего не работает и в консоле никаких ошибок,  код такой:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller = "dishDetailController as dishCtrl">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="media-list media-list tab-pane fade in active">
          <div class="media" ng-repeat="dish in dishCtrl.dish">
           <div class="media-left media-middle">
            <a href="#">
             <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
             ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
           </a>
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
           <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
           <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
         </h2>
         <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
 <p><h4>Customer Comments</h4>Sort by:<input type="text" id="comm">

  <blockquote ng-repeat="comment in dishCtrl.dish.comments">
    <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
    <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
    <footer>John Lemon</footer>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

var dish=[{
  name:'Uthapizza',
  image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
  category: 'mains', 
  label:'Hot',
  price:'4.99',
  description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
  comments: [
  {
   rating:5,
   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
   author:"John Lemon",
   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
 },
 {
   rating:4,
   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
   author:"Paul McVites",
   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
 },
 {
   rating:3,
   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
 },
 {
   rating:4,
   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
   author:"Ringo Starry",
   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
 },
 {
   rating:2,
   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
   author:"25 Cent",
   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
 }

 ]
 }
 ];

  this.dish = dish;

 });

 </script>
```

Comment: `dishCtrl.dish.comments` не существует, атрибут `comments` определён у элемента списка `dishCtrl.dish`

Comment: и как к нему доступиться?                                                      `<blockquote ng-repeat="comments in dishDetailController.dish">
        <p>{{comments.rating}} Stars</p>
        <p>{{comments.comment}}</p>
        <footer>John Lemon</footer>
  </blockquote>  ` Так тоже не работает(

Comment: например, в контроллере вынести комментарии ко всем блюдам в отдельную коллекцию

Comment: У вас элемент `blockquote ng-repeat="comment in dishCtrl.dish.comments">` находится вне контроллера `dishDetailController`.